# Python 3 UTF-8 encoding doesnt really work

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have read a lot now on the topic of UTF-8 encoding in Python 3 but it still doesn't work, and I can't find my mistake.

My code looks like this

```
def main():

    with open("test.txt", "rU", encoding='utf-8') as test_file:
        text = test_file.read()
    print(str(len(text)))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

My `test.txt` file looks like this

```
ö
```

And I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Your file is not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Its a testfile. I should write a programm in Python3 that is able to read it. And write it out again. And it Should be in UTF-8.

Comment: Two things are wrong here - either your file is not UTF-8, and if it isn't it has something other than `ä` in it.

Comment: I got the testfile from the server of the university. So i guess the file should be ok. Intressing is that i can read the file with open(test.txt).read() and it works without a problem ... I don't get it.

Comment: @GVVMultigamingClan: `open()` *without* `encoding` takes your *system default* as the encoding. If `open('test.txt').read()` works then the file is **not** UTF-8 but whatever [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) returns.

Comment: I finaly found the solution. The file was not in UTF-8. We learned in the lecture to open "all" files for this course with open("file", "rU",encoding='UTF-8'). Well the Tutor that created the simple tescase did a mistake and created a file in ascii... Pretty anoying i waste more then 1 hour on this problem... I thank you for the help.

Answer (score 7):

Your file is not UTF-8 encoded. I'm not sure what encoding uses F6 for `ä` either; that codepoint is the encoding for `ö` in Latin 1 and CP-1252:

```
>>> b'\xf6'.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 0: invalid start byte
>>> b'\xf6'.decode('latin1')
'ö'
```

You'll need to save that file as UTF-8 instead, with whatever tool you used to create that file.

If `open('text').read()` works, then you were able to decode the file using the default system encoding. See the [`open()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> *encoding* is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file. This should only be used in text mode. The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) returns), but any encoding supported by Python can be used.

That is not to say that you were reading the file using the correct encoding; that just means that the default encoding didn't break (encountered bytes for which it doesn't have a character mapping). It could still be mapping those bytes to the wrong characters.

I *urge* you to read up on Unicode and Python:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder